# NSNotification vs UITextFieldDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, nsnotifications

My colleagues and I prefer different approaches to solving one small task. We would like to know opinion of the community.

We have to process UITextField's text during editing. ( Text should be displayed in the view's title )

Two simplest approaches are:

1.Register for notifications:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(textFieldDidChangeNotification:)
                                             name:UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification
                                           object:_titleTextField];
```

2.Use UITextFieldDelegate method

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSMutableString *mutableString = [textField.text mutableCopy];
    [mutableString replaceCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    // use mutableString for father processing

    return YES;
}
```

Which approach is better and why? Is there any reason why some approach should be avoided in this situation?

UPDATE: ( Some clarifications )

We do not need any additional flexibility that is provided by delegate ( like possibility to disallow some editing) or notifications ( possibility to add several observers ). Our main question is "Is it a good practice to use NSNotifications if we can easily solve an issue with delegate?"

UPDATE2:

Thanks everyone who answered the question!

It seems that community's answer for question "is it a good practice to use NSNotifications if we can easily solve an issue with delegate?" is yes. But for our original issue we have found another (third) variant which is better than delegates and NSNotification (see accepted answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since UITextField inherits from UIControl we also can use `addTarget: action: forControlEvents:`

```
[_textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods of a `UITextFieldDelegate` will return `YES` or `NO` depending on whether you want the user to be allowed to type certain things.

With this in mind, I'd use a notification. You don't care about the logic for changing the content of the `UITextField`, all you want to do is, whenever the content is changed, change the title of your view.

This gives you the benefit of allowing any `delegate` to still be able to return `YES` or `NO` if the content needs to be restricted and the notification will only be sent if the delegate has returned `YES` (or if there is no delegate).

**EDIT**

In case I misunderstood the question, process the text in the `UITextFieldDelegate` method and use the notification to update the view's title. Unless the `UITextFieldDelegate` is the view, in which case I'd just update the view's title directly from the `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

**EDIT #2**

Based on your further edit and requirements I would hands down use the delegate method. `NSNotification` comes with issues that delegates don't - debugging and performance (as RobP mentioned) is one. Another is it's much easier to leave an `NSNotification` hanging around after you have dealloc'd whatever it was attached to, resulting in a crash (good look debugging, see RobP's answer).

In your specific circumstances, delegate wins.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

I have coded a lot of both and I disagree with Adam. Notifications prove much harder to debug and trace backward most of the time. I also suspect they add more performance overhead, but that's anecdotal for me and I have not benchmarked it.
I lean toward notifications when there may be more than one observer that needs to act on an event, and/or when I want "loose coupling" where one part of the code shouldn't have specific knowledge of API's in another part.
In your case, the text field already comes with the logic to have a delegate and make calls to the delegate on certain events so it's a no-brainer. If one or more delegate methods get called at the time you need with the data you need. that's the simpler, more appropriate path.

Comment: Will be interested to see where peoples' votes fall and what other pros and cons people bring up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have updated the question to make it more clear.

Comment: @Avt for the reasons I gave, I still think a delegate is the way to go even if you use only a minimal part of the delegate protocol, and are just returning whatever boolean result you get from passing the call to super.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between delegate and notification is that notification will notify all classes, in case they have subscribed to it. While delegate is one to one.

Considering that there won't be any further changes in application work flow. This approaches a pretty much equal. But I still prefer to use delegate because of following reasons:

- it's more common approach, so it will make your code more readable and maintainable;
- using notification you are have to subscribe to it, so it's extra lines. Not so many but ViewControllers usually are the largest classes in ios applications.
- notifications use event DID while delegate use SHOLUD, so if you need to prevent your textfield from entering smth SHOULD fits better